# How to uninstall ubuntu form windows or manually

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I installed ubuntu 14.0 over my windows and now I want to remove ubuntu. But when I try to uninstall from control panel then I cant figure out the ubuntu icon...can u please help me? Thank You

Comment: Possible location for this question is [stackoverflow superuser](http://superuser.stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do is:

1. Start Windows from disk and go to repair Windows (this will delete Ubuntu boot-loader)
2. Format Ubuntu partition

If you want, later you can merge ex-Ubuntu partition with some of existing partitions on your HD